# What is String.Encoding.unicode?

Tags: swift, string, unicode, encoding, swift-string

Swift offers a series of encodings for strings. As of the time I'm writing this, [none of them are documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding#2851053), which makes this absurdly more confusing than it should be...

I can understand that [`.ascii`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding/1780368-ascii) means it's [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoded, [`.utf8`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding/1780106-utf8) means the string is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded, and [`.utf16BigEndian`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding/1780147-utf16bigendian) means the string is [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) but [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). These obviously map to real text encodings.

Then there's [`.unicode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding/1779974-unicode). There is no "Unicode" encoding. [The Unicode standard defines UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), which, as I said above, are already defined in Swift.

**Is it a fancy one which figures out the best one for the system? Is it an alias for `.utf8`? Is it some weird Apple Unicode encoding?**

Comment: In many frameworks, "unicode" usually means UTF-16 in the underlying platform's native endian.

Comment: @RemyLebeau really? I figured it'd be UTF-16. Do you know why, or have somewhere I can read more about that?

Comment: This is a presentation I saw a couple of months ago at a Swift conference. It filled in a lot of blanks for me re: unicode. https://github.com/rachelhyman/emoji/blob/master/presentation.pdf

Comment: Thanks! Also I must've been really tired in my previous comment; I meant I figured it'd be UTF-8. I'll look through it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear to be an alias for `.utf16`. From `CFString.h`:

```
#define kCFStringEncodingInvalidId (0xffffffffU)
typedef CF_ENUM(CFStringEncoding, CFStringBuiltInEncodings) {
    kCFStringEncodingMacRoman = 0,
    kCFStringEncodingWindowsLatin1 = 0x0500, /* ANSI codepage 1252 */
    kCFStringEncodingISOLatin1 = 0x0201, /* ISO 8859-1 */
    kCFStringEncodingNextStepLatin = 0x0B01, /* NextStep encoding*/
    kCFStringEncodingASCII = 0x0600, /* 0..127 (in creating CFString, values greater than 0x7F are treated as corresponding Unicode value) */
    kCFStringEncodingUnicode = 0x0100, /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault  + kTextEncodingDefaultFormat (aka kUnicode16BitFormat) */
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8 = 0x08000100, /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF8Format */
    kCFStringEncodingNonLossyASCII = 0x0BFF, /* 7bit Unicode variants used by Cocoa & Java */

    kCFStringEncodingUTF16 = 0x0100, /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF16Format (alias of kCFStringEncodingUnicode) */
    kCFStringEncodingUTF16BE = 0x10000100, /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF16BEFormat */
    kCFStringEncodingUTF16LE = 0x14000100, /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF16LEFormat */

    kCFStringEncodingUTF32 = 0x0c000100, /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF32Format */
    kCFStringEncodingUTF32BE = 0x18000100, /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF32BEFormat */
    kCFStringEncodingUTF32LE = 0x1c000100 /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF32LEFormat */
};
```

You can confirm this with:

```
print(String.Encoding.unicode.rawValue, String.Encoding.utf16.rawValue)
```

Comment: I did notice that in Swift, but was concerned this was some platform-dependent thing. There are other such seemingly-generated headers around Cocoa which give me pause, like `TargetConditionals.h`. Hopefully this is not one of them. Can you think of any way to test this possibility?

Comment: Feel free to peruse the source of truth, [swift-corelibs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation). E.g., see [`String.Encoding` definitions here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/c82e1deba471bc9d26516c332f25578551356d9f/Foundation/StringEncodings.swift), mappings between [`NSString` and `CFString` codings here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/155f1ce1965effe55289477507a6f9fbdc8fe333/CoreFoundation/String.subproj/CFStringUtilities.c#L210), etc. Just the same, I’d stick with `.utf8`/`16` variants, not `.unicode`.